# nodejs .execSync will not return data when calling from within a child forked process

Tags: node.js

I have my main.js
doing the following:

```
const fork = require('child_process').fork;
fork(myprocess........)
```

This all works fine....

Now inside the myprocess.js

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
var foo = execSync('myspecialprogram')
console.log(foo.toString());
```

Result of foo is empty buffer.

How do I get the execSync to return data from within the forked child process?

Comment: when i run myprocess.js as a regular process not via fork, it returns buffer data fine.

Comment: Might be related to incorrectly set current working directory.

Comment: how to check/fix, running windows

Answer (score 0):

anyway, i think its actually workign fine, somehow the spawn process im running was retunring empty value. So its fine.